# What is the difference between swaplevel() and reorder_levels()?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

While working with hierarchical index levels in pandas, what is the difference between [`swaplevel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and [`reorder_levels()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When there only two levels `swaplevel` and `reorder_levels` almost same , but when your df have more than 3 levels , personally think `reorder_levels` is more elegant way

For example :

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3],[1,1,1]])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=idx, index=[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

IF we want to change the order level=[0,1,2,3] to [3,2,1,0]

With `swaplevel` : need multiple calls

```
df.swaplevel(0,3,axis=1).swaplevel(1,2,axis=1)
     1          
     3          
     1    2     
     1    1    2
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

With `reorder_levels` : Only one call

```
df.reorder_levels([3,2,1,0],axis=1)
     1          
     3          
     1    2     
     1    1    2
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
```