# creating multi index from data grouped by month in Pandas

Tags: pandas, transformation

Consider this sample data:

```
Month  Location  Products    Sales  Profit
JAN      1        43          32     20  
JAN      2        82          54     25
JAN      3        64          43     56
FEB      1        37          28     78
FEB      2        18          15     34
FEB      3        5           2      4
MAR      1        47          40     14
```

The multi-index transformation I am trying to achieve is this:

```
          JAN                     FEB                     MAR
Location  Products Sales Profit   Products Sales Profit   Products Sales Profit
1         43       32    29       37       28    78       47       40    14
2         82       54    25       18       15    34       null     null  null
3         64       43    56       5        2     4        null     null  null
```

I tried versions of this:

```
df.stack().to_frame().T
```

It put all the data into one row.  So, that's not the goal.
I presume I am close in that it should be a stacking or unstacking, melting or unmelting, but my attempts have all resulted in data oatmeal at this point.  Appreciate your time trying to solve this one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pivot`:

```
>>> df.pivot('Location', 'Month').swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

Month         FEB                   JAN                   MAR             
         Products Profit Sales Products Profit Sales Products Profit Sales
Location                                                                  
1            37.0   78.0  28.0     43.0   20.0  32.0     47.0   14.0  40.0
2            18.0   34.0  15.0     82.0   25.0  54.0      NaN    NaN   NaN
3             5.0    4.0   2.0     64.0   56.0  43.0      NaN    NaN   NaN
```

**To preserve order**, you have to transform your `Month` column as `CategoricalDtype` before:

```
df['Month'] = df['Month'].astype(pd.CategoricalDtype(df['Month'].unique(), ordered=True))
out = df.pivot('Location', 'Month').swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print(out)

# Output:
Month         JAN                   FEB                   MAR             
         Products Profit Sales Products Profit Sales Products Profit Sales
Location                                                                  
1            43.0   20.0  32.0     37.0   78.0  28.0     47.0   14.0  40.0
2            82.0   25.0  54.0     18.0   34.0  15.0      NaN    NaN   NaN
3            64.0   56.0  43.0      5.0    4.0   2.0      NaN    NaN   NaN
```

**Update 2**

Try to force the order of level 2 columns:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Month', 'Location'])
df1.columns = pd.CategoricalIndex(df1.columns, ordered=True)
df1 = df1.unstack('Month').swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Comment: Both suggested answers create the multi-index, however, interestingly, both also re_order the columns so that the result has under each month, Sales, Profit then Products.  Can they be adjusted so the result is Products, Profit, Sales?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @JohnTaylor. Do you miss my update? I think we wrote in the same time :)

Comment: The Month column was already set as Categorical, but I ran your update and got the same result of re-ordered columns last is now first, etc.  Still tinkering.....

Comment: I don't understand. If you look for Product, Profit, Sales, it's already the correct order no?

Comment: Yes.  It is in the sample data.  When I enter this code on my actual data, it is re-ordering those three columns for some reason.  I am sure it is something I am doing wrong.

Comment: You can create a Categorical for your column before pivoting. I will update my answer soon.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this.  My Month Column was already categorical in my original dataframe.  I checked that with .info().  So, that is not my current issue I don't think.

Comment: @JohnTaylor. I updated my answer. Now columns are ordered by `CategoricalIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`reorder_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html) and  [`sort_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df.pivot(index='Location',columns='Month').reorder_levels(order=[1,0],axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

Month         FEB                   JAN                   MAR             
         Products Profit Sales Products Profit Sales Products Profit Sales
Location                                                                  
1            37.0   78.0  28.0     43.0   20.0  32.0     47.0   14.0  40.0
2            18.0   34.0  15.0     82.0   25.0  54.0      NaN    NaN   NaN
3             5.0    4.0   2.0     64.0   56.0  43.0      NaN    NaN   NaN
```

In case you are interested, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54191730/what-is-the-difference-between-swaplevel-and-reorder-levels) answer elaborates between `swaplevel` and `reoder_levels`.

Comment: I figured out what is happening, but not how to solve it.  My actual column names are not Product, Profit and Sales (which are in alpha order just by chance).  But, instead are more like Cherry, Apple, Banana and each answer above re_orders the columns in alpha order, meaning, they appear in the results as Apple, Banana, Cherry, out of the order I want them in.